# Proof of Factor Price Equalization

Tags: international-economics

Assumptions:

1. 2 nations - 1 and 2
2. 2 goods X and Y where X is labour intensive and Y is capital intensive
3. Perfect competition across commodities market
4. same technology in both nations
5. both face constant returns to scale

We are assuming all the assumptions of the Hecksher-Ohlin model to be true but I wrote that might be required specifically for the question.

Corollary of Hecksher-Ohlin theorem is Factor-Price Equalisation which states:

International trade will bring about equalization in the relative and absolute returns to homogenous factors (capital and labour) across nations.

Question: Does Absolute factor price equalization imply relative factor price equalization? The reason why I am asking this question is that if absolute factor price equalization is proven, it automatically implies that relative factor-price equalization is proven unless the proof of absolute factor price equalization assumes relative factor-price equalization.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "*if absolute factor price equalization is proven, it automatically implies factor-price equalization is proven unless absolute factor price equalisation assumes factor-price equalisation*" Perhaps it's me, but I can't make heads or tails of this sentence.

Comment: does this make sense @Giskard. thanks though!!

Comment: No, not really. You seem to be asking: "does $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 = y_2$ imply $x_1/x_2 = y_1/y_2$?"

Comment: Also, does your proof of absolute factor-price equalization assume relative factor-price equalization? Perhaps link to it/include it in your question?

Comment: your previous comment $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 = y_2$ imply $x_1/x_2 = y_1/y_2$ actually does answer my question which is yes (as in proof of absolute factor-price equalization => relative factor-price equalization).

Actually, I was trying to evade the proof of relative factor price equalization which has a long explanation. 

I just realised that the proof absolute factor-price equalization is using the diagram used in the proof of relative factor-price equalization. 

I am trying to paste the picture here from salvatore but it doesnt let me!